# Posts Page in WordPress loading bare HTML of my homepage

Tags: posts, errors, html

On my WordPress site, I have an HTML page template serving as the home page and the posts page is a generic WP posts page. However, whichever page I set as the Posts Page in the Reading section of WP Dashboard, ends up loading the bare HTML of my homepage. I don't understand how or why this may be happening. Has anyone faced something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the problem. There was a home.php file in my themes directory in wp-content. Due to the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) of WordPress, the blogs page was reading from this home.php file, where I had some HTML. Since I was the one who had created this file, on deleting it, the Posts page worked correctly.